# WSL on VSCode for Windows - Live Server Extension not working

Tags: javascript, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-extensions, liveserver

I have searched through several other posts, and nothing has fixed my issue yet. I'm working in WSL, through VSCode also using the Linux Subsystem.  Live server will not open; it just says "Port:5500" as if it was connected, but nothing pops up.

When I use normal VSCode, not through the Linux Subsystem, Live server works perfectly fine.

I've done everything I can to try to get it to work, and it's been decreasing my performance because I have to write my code on my normal code editor on Windows in order to use live server, then copy & paste my code to my other file after I know it's right.  It's very tedious.

Anyone on insight with how to get live server working with WSL would be a tremendous help.

Comment: what happens if you navigate in your browser to localhost:5500? I guess it cant open a browser because you dont have one in wsl, but its still liestening on the port. So try navigating yourself in there by using a browser that you have installed in windows.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that with several different browsers that I have installed. Nothing works. I've went to Live Server Config in VSCode & played around with the settings even tried switching the paths. My files are saved in the Linux directory on my Windows PC, I think the path is off somewhere but I can't seem to find a way to switch the path with WSL even though there are separate settings for WSL/Workspace in VSCode.

Comment: It was never meant to be your fight, so report it to the developers and wait, https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues